# Possible configurations of a tree having incomplete information

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I'm looking for a math application that would detect all possible trees that are compatible with an incomplete description. For being more concrete, I'm trying to detect all possible skeletons that are compatible with a known set of joints. 
At this moment I'm reviewing some papers on combinatorics group theory, but they're pretty abstract and it's hard to find applied use cases. 
Any hint in the right direction will be welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "math application", also what would an incomplete description look like? An example might be helpful

Comment: I mean a technique, or a branch of

Comment: I mean any technicque that can solve my problem. As an example, imagine a tree that has two branches and each branch has another two branches. Suposse we have one instance of this tree, but partial information about how its edges are connected, for instance we are sure that there is a four connected edge path joining four known edges. Then if you have to determine where the other vertices should connect, it is clear that there are only two possible configurations that fit into the known structure. That is the problem I want to solve: identify all the possible ways the tree can be completed.

Comment: This is sounding a lot like constructing all trees with a particular degree sequence